# Application not starting until form is displayed to user for the first time

Tags: c++, .net, mfc, process

This is a weird question.  I have written a .NET application that starts a process.  This process is a MFC application written in c++.  For some reason the process does not start doing anything until the form is displayed to the user for the first time.  For example, if the process starts minimized I have to un-minimize it (click on it) before it will start doing whatever it's supposed to do.  Also, if my application is running and starting this process while the screen is locked the process behaves the same as if it's minimized.  It doesn't start doing anything until I unlock the screen and it is displayed to the user for the first time.  Like I said, this is a weird question so I hope I'm conveying the problem properly.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your functionality is embedded in MFC Windows' load event. If you want the application to be more reactive, move that code to your application class.

Comment: I have no access to the code in that application so I can't add it to mine.

Comment: then there is no solution, you cannot expect an UI application to behave as a background process.